# How to return a has_one relation where it either being created with a false default value or not being created at all

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a table called users and it has one priority.

Priority has a default called as initialized which is set to false.

I wanna return all users who either don't have priority or who has priority with initialized = false.

Right now I fetch in this way.

```
User.includes(:priority).where(priorities: {user_id: nil}) + 
User.joins(:priority).where({'priorities.initialized' => false})
```

Is there a way to combine both way and get the required data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that priority is another table, not an attribute, this might work:

```
User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN priorities ON priorities.user_id = users.id').where('priorities.id is NULL OR priorities.initialized = ?', false)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)